# How can I get DBD::Pg to time out reliably?

Tags: perl, signals, dbi

Why doesn't this code execute the signal handler until after $sth->execute completes?  And more importantly, how can I fix it?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use DBI;
use Sys::SigAction qw( set_sig_handler );

my $dbh = DBI->connect('dbi:Pg:dbname=dc');

eval {
    my $h = set_sig_handler('ALRM', sub { die "timeout\n" });
    eval {
        alarm 1;
        my $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT pg_sleep(10)");
        print "Before execute\n";
        $sth->execute;
        print "After execute\n";
        $sth->finish;
    };
    alarm 0;
    die "$@" if $@;
};
die "$@" if $@;
print "Finished\n";
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider using Pg's [asynchronous query](http://p3rl.org/DBD%3a%3aPg#Asynchronous_Queries) feature instead.

Comment: Yeah, I also tried that.  Unfortunately, there's no way to wait for the same query without also freezing at the same place.  That is, unless I want to use a sleep loop, which adds unnecessary delays.

Answer (score 1):

Due to changes in the way Perl handles signals (so-called "safe signals" as of 5.8.0), you'll need to use [Perl::Unsafe::Signals](http://search.cpan.org/~rgarcia/Perl-Unsafe-Signals-0.02/Signals.pm) to allow your `die()` to work when `$sth->execute` is in progress.

Answer (score 1):

There is [AnyEvent::Pg](https://metacpan.org/module/AnyEvent::Pg) that allows to query PostgreSQL asynchronously, though, it is not DBI compatible and it will force you to rewrite your app/script on top of [AnyEvent](https://metacpan.org/module/AnyEvent).